# How to accept only one decimal point value in textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an instance of `UITextField`. I has keyboard type as number pad, so that user can enter only decimal value. But I'm able to enter value as **2.4.5.5**. Please tell how can restrict user to enter value only like 2.4

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if ([textField.text containsString:@"."] && [string containsString:@"."]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: That implies no dot should be allowed

Comment: We're still doing Objective C in 2017?? Swift 4 is out already, no?

Answer (score 0):

I created sample project and I tried.I got exact solution.Check my answer below.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet].location != NSNotFound)
        return NO;
    else {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSArray *arrSep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        if([arrSep count] > 2)
            return NO;
        else {
            if([arrSep count] == 1) {
                if([[arrSep objectAtIndex:0] length] > 9)
                    return NO;
                else
                    return YES;
            }
            if([arrSep count] == 2) {
                if([[arrSep objectAtIndex:0] length] > 9)
                    return NO;
                else if([[arrSep objectAtIndex:1] length] > 2)  //Set after dot(.) how many digits you want.I set after dot I want 2 digits.If it goes more than 2 return NO
                    return NO;
                else {
                    if([[arrSep objectAtIndex:0] length] >= 10) //Again I set the condition here.
                        return NO;
                    else
                        return YES;
                }
            }
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Output

First I enter 9 digits with dot according to condition.

[image]

Then I enter your input 2.4.After 2.4 if I try to give another dot it does not allow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this (It worked for me):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


        NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];
        NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];
        BOOL isNumbersOnly = ([numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField]);
        if (!isNumbersOnly) {
            return NO;
        }
        if ([string rangeOfString:@"."].location !=NSNotFound && [textField.text rangeOfString:string].location !=NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```